# Strapi Roles and Permission plugin doesnt exist in side bar?

Tags: strapi

I setted up Strapi through NPX and ran

```
npx create-strapi-app my-project --quickstart
```

I am using strapi and here is my side bar

[image]

Normally i expected it to be like the following:

[image]

I dont know why but I cannot access Roles & Permission tab as it is not there. I  need this tab for API permission customization.
I checked the docs and it says that is should be there following:

> "This plugin provides a way to protect your API with a full
> authentication process based on JWT. This plugin comes also with an
> ACL strategy that allows you to manage the permissions between the
> groups of users.
>
> To access the plugin admin panel, click on the Roles & Pemissions link
> in the left menu."

I have no idea what is wrong with my dashboard. How may i access this plugin?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Okay, strange enough I wasted 30 minutes on this, so it turns out ***they decided to change their UI in version 3.x*** and somehow when you search for "Roles & Permissions strapi" on google, it leads you to old documents, which is frustrating and misleading :))))

[New docs link here](https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/users-permissions.html#concept)

> Roles & Permissions. This plugin provides a way to protect your API
> with a full authentication process based on JWT. This plugin comes
> also with an ACL strategy that allows you to manage the permissions
> between the groups of users.
>
> To access the plugin admin panel, click on the Settings link in the
> left menu and then everything will be under the USERS & PERMISSIONS
> PLUGIN section.
>
> #Concept

Comment: yea I also have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: You need to go to admin panel, click on the Settings link in the left menu and then everything will be under the USERS & PERMISSIONS PLUGIN section. Pess user or auth and the old menu will open. Its as if they hid it lol

Answer (score 2):

If you in version3.x
Go to Settings -> User & Permission -> Roles -> Authenticated or Public -> on Permissions Widget --> select Application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Strapi v4.x, install the plugin and it will be shown on the sidebar:

```
npm i @strapi/plugin-users-permissions
```